# Stack trace skipping functions

Tags: .net, debugging, exception, f#, stack-trace

I'm looking at stack traces generated in F#, and they are skipping functions. A test case:

```
let foo() =
    failwithf "foo"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    foo()
    0
```

Compiled with debug info, and run:

```
(torch) C:\t>fsc -g test.fs
Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 10.8.0.0 for F# 4.7
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

(torch) C:\t>test

Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: foo
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatToStringThenFail@1637.Invoke(String message)
   at Test.main(String[] argv) in C:\t\test.fs:line 7
```

It says the exception was generated from `main`, with no mention of `foo` where it was actually generated.

How do I get the full stack trace, including the function that actually generated the exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have been the victim of optimizations, which make debugging difficult in any toolchain.

Please note that for `fsc`, optimizations are [turned on by default](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/0f514efe25899ba59778b5bb522e2724aec44a3d/src/fsharp/FSharp.Build/Fsc.fs#L120).
They are:

**Inlining**

`foo()` isn't even called - it's a simple static method, which can be easily inlined.
The resulting IL is equivalent to:

```
let main argv =
    PrintfModule.PrintFormatToStringThenFail(new PrintfFormat<_>("foo"));
    0
```

We can turn this off with `--optimize-`

```
fsc -g --optimize- Program.fs
```

But this still isn't enough. Because of...

**Tail-call optimization**

A tail-call optimization lets you avoid allocating a new stack frame for a function. `foo` is a simple function which shorts `main`. And since there's no stack frame, you don't see it in the stack trace.

We can turn this off with `--tailcalls-`.

For the full debugging experience, go with what VS basically does for `DEBUG`:

```
fsc --debug:full --define:DEBUG --define:TRACE --optimize- --tailcalls- Program.fs
```

Now if we run our target, we get the stacktrace as expected:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: foo
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatToStringThenFail@1639.Invoke(String message)
   at Program.foo[a]() in Program.fs:line 4
   at Program.main(String[] argv) in Program.fs:line 13
```